# SQL combining two tables without duplication

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to combine two tables based on a column. Here's an example:

These are my two tables:

```
    Table1                  Table2

Person | salary        Person | Age
Tim    |  22.50        Larry  | 32
Tony   |  49.00        Tim    | 22
John   |  32.67        Tony   | 44
Kim    |  23.42        John   | 31
```

And my resulting table should be:

```
Person | salary | Age
Larry  |        | 32
Tim    |  22.50 | 22 
Tony   |  49.00 | 44
John   |  32.67 | 31
Kim    |  23.42 |
```

Everyone is added to the resulting table only once even if they don't have a value for both salary and age

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you want us to write sql query for you?

Comment: Look up `FULL OUTER JOIN`, have a go, and then post back if you still have problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have tagged this as MS-ACCESS I will provide SQL code for MS ACCESS

Because Microsoft does not have the capability to do a FULL OUTER JOIN, you have to think of a clever way to use existing SQL commands to create a FULL OUTER JOIN. The following code should do the trick using your tables above:

```
SELECT Table1.Person, Salary, Age
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Person = Table2.Person
UNION ALL
SELECT Table1.Person, Salary, Age
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Person = Table2.Person
WHERE Table2.Person Is Null
UNION ALL
SELECT Table2.Person, Salary, Age
FROM Table1 RIGHT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Person = Table2.Person
WHERE Table1.Person Is Null
```

Answer (score 0):

This could have been done by full outer join but since you are using ms access you will have to use **union all** in the below manner.
Try this out and let me know in case you face any difficulties.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN 
table2 t2
ON t1.person = t2.person
UNION all
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
RIGHT JOIN 
table2 t2
ON t1.person = t2.person
```

Comment: No it didn't..the resulting table has two copies of the Person column and it has two copies of each value

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what's your problem exactly but here is a SQL query that will do just what you have requested:

```
SELECT Person, salary, Age
FROM Table1 FULL OUTER JOIN Table2
WHERE Table1.Person = Table2.Person
```

Edit: This won't work on MS-ACCESS for its lack of support for FULL OUTER JOINS, the other two answers have explained the alternative.